# Loss increasing with batch normalization (tf.Keras)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, batch-normalization

I have a FF NN with 2 hidden layers for a regression problem. Compared to when I do not add BN, loss (MSE) is about double when training on the same number of epochs, and the execution time is also increased by about 20%. Why is that?

If I had to take a guess -- BN is not worth it on a 2-layer network, and the extra overhead introduced by BN is actually higher than whatever decrease in processing time it causes.

That would explain the execution time, but I am not sure why the loss is higher, too.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, 'relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(128, 'relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1, 'linear'))
model.compile(loss=mean_squared_error, optimizer='adam')
```

I've tried a variety of optimizers, activation functions, number of epochs, batch size, etc, but no difference.

Answer (score 2):

For regression, you should not use `BatchNorm` before the `output` layer.

On the other hand, you could use  `BatchNorm` right after the `input` layer and before the first `Dense` layer to normalize inputs.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! What's your reasoning on this? I could not find any resources suggesting this.

Comment: @svdc Did it solve your problem? For reason, I suggest you doing some experiments yourself, measuring the output after BN, regression output, and classification output for each batch. Notice the logic of prediction function in case of regression and classification, then it's obvious.